# typescript: string representation of generic T

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to create a generic method, that receives a generic `<T>`, and I need to use a string of what `<T>` is inside the method

We consume the API passing the name of the Entity as a parameter: `http://server/api/fetch/Entity/123`

where I need to know that `<T>` is:

```js
    public get<T>() {
        const response = super.doRequest("/api/fetch/<T>/123");
        return response as T;
    }
```

when I call the method I know what I'm looking for (`JobView`):

```js
    this.baseService.get<JobView>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The type system is completely [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) when the compiler emits JavaScript.  There is no `T` at runtime.  Instead, you'll have to pass an actual string value to the `get()` method.

You can get some intelligent typing if you make a mapping from entity name as passed to `doRequest()` to the entity type.  For example:

```
interface EntityMap {
    JobView: JobView;
    OtherEntity: OtherEntity;
    EtCetera: EtCetera;
}
```

There don't need to be any objects of type `EntityMap` at runtime; it's just a helper type that the compiler uses to understand that the name e.g., `"JobView"` corresponds to the type `JobView`.  Mapping from names to types is something interfaces do well, so that's why we're using it.

---

Then, your `get()` method might look like this:

```
public get<K extends keyof EntityMap>(entityName: K) {
    const response = super.doRequest("/api/fetch/" + entityName + "/123");
    return response as EntityMap[K];
}
```

So you are passing in an `entityName` parameter of generic type `K` that must match `keyof EntityMap`... namely `"JobView"`, `"OtherEntity"`, or `"EtCetera"`.  So now at runtime, the value `entityName` can be used to call `doRequest()`.  Then the response will be returned as type `EntityMap[K]`, where we [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) the `K`-named property in `EntityMap`.  So you can use it like this:

```
const r = new RequestyThing();
const jv = r.get("JobView");
// const jv: JobView
```

and you'll see that when you call `r.get("JobView")`, the compiler returns a value of type `JobView`.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=36&ssc=21&pln=34&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDyAuALApgJwErII4FdkXgE8AVRASwDsBzaAbwChonoATAe0133gAodUQALmgFUlKgEphYCoTqNmi1Mnj8K0CjhAgAhAG4FTAL70T9SvDQAzMMGTQAUmwBGANTLIA7vMVkWw0XEDRQArFwD4MWpg5go2AEkWZDBhTQBbZzQDMwtrW3sEFFQAUQp4MiIfWLA05Aioqmz6czK8u2hi+ABhFTQwKqYkcUJhZzY2EGSKJpbLVBt20vKiAFkwAAcBxxd3L2EnNw9PGKZCtCWKkbgkc7LLk47u3tQUx565sBnQSBhOPAISORqNBkAAPSwUFgwM4YbD-IikcRbdY4ZwgMjAaBUFQAHgA0iDwchITAANbIQhsKwdO6rDYAPh4xOWhAAcjU6tA8RItopgGwKARoMoIOsBRB7ABeEQ4dZoAB07D+3B4ACIAPQbMjqqwqYCIdWq6AAahBtLZHJN0A1AEYAEwAZlVEgeShUamF+DFgvskBpLLW6wA2niALoPExmfmC+DC6DSiheaDKgGI6g8F30aNCkIAN3jwvl2N4qoOu08zoM6vV0Gzsbz+x2RyAA)

Comment: How it didn't occur to me! It, like, parses it, it's not available after that... oh boy... thanks!!!